# How do I separate routes in my given express file?

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I want to separate my routes in from my app.js file but it also has functions so I am not sure how to import stuff and separate functions from app.js file,what needs to stay and what doesnt
My app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');

var passport=require('passport');
var passportLocal=require('passport-local').Strategy;
var path = require('path');

var cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession=require('express-session');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var controlleri=require('./controllers/controller_2');
var mongoose_controller=require('./controllers/mongoose_controller');
var user_controller=require('./controllers/user_controller');
var booking_controller=require('./controllers/booking_controller');
var login_message;
var therapist_controller =require('./controllers/therapist_controller');

app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded( {extended:false}));

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret:'secret',
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use('local',new passportLocal(function(username,password,done){

 user_controller.login(username,password,function(value) {
    if (value) {


      done(null, {
        id: username,
        type: true
      });

    } 
    else {

      done(null, null);
    }
}
);
}));

passport.use('local2',new passportLocal(function(username,password,done){
    console.log(username+password+"haha");

 therapist_controller.login(username,password,function(value) {
    if (value) {

        console.log("logged from server");
      done(null, {
        id: username,
        type: false
      });

    } 
    else {
   console.log("logged not from server");
      done(null, null);
    }
}
);
}));



app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){

    done(null,user)

});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,{id:user.id,type:user.type});
});




app.get('/therapist_data',mongoose_controller.finds);

app.get('/api/booking/user',user_controller.getuser);

app.get('/api/session_data',function(req,res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        var users=JSON.stringify(req.user.name);
        console.log(users);
        res.send(req.user.name);
    }else{
        res.send(401);
    }
});

app.get('/era',controlleri.create);

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.redirect('/home');
    }else{
    res.render(__dirname+'/client/views/login',{
        error:""
    });
}
});

app.get('/register',function(req,res){
    res.render(__dirname+'/client/views/register',{
        error:""
    });
});

app.get('/api/booking/user/adress',user_controller.getaddress);

app.post('/register',user_controller.register);



app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home',
   failureRedirect: '/loginerror'
    }));

app.get('/loginerror',function(req,res){
    res.render(__dirname+'/client/views/login',{
        error:"Invalid username or password"
    });
});

app.post('/loginerror',passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/home',
   failureRedirect: '/loginerror'
    }));

app.get('/home',function(req,res){

    if(req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.type){
        console.log("true");
        console.log(req.user.type);
        res.render(__dirname+'/client/views/home',{
        isAuthenticated:true,
        user:req.user
    });

    }else{
        console.log("false");

        res.render(__dirname+'/client/views/home',{
        isAuthenticated:false,
        user:req.user
    });
    }




});

app.get('/therapist-select-days',function(req,res){
    res.render(__dirname+'/client/views/therapist_days_select')
});

app.get('/api/get_booked_days',therapist_controller.get_booked_days);

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/home');
});

app.post('/era',function(req,res){
    console.log("got request");
    controlleri.book(req,res);
    booking_controller.book(req,res);
    console.log("done in server.js");

});

app.post('/api/therapist/book_days',controlleri.bookDates);

app.post('/ur-book',function(req,res){

    console.log("got post request");
    controlleri.book(req,res);
    booking_controller.bookur(req,res);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("done in server.js");
});

app.post('/api/therapist-login',passport.authenticate('local2'),function(req,res){
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('okay');
});

app.post('/therapist-register',therapist_controller.register);
app.get('/api/therapist-home',function(req,res){
    if(req.user && !req.user.type){
        console.log("allowed");
        res.send(req.user);


    }else{
        console.log("not allowed");
        res.send(401);
    }
});

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/client/views/index.html');
});





app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("server strated");
})

// catch 404 and forward to error handler

module.exports = app;
```

Note the last contains even the angular routes so do I need to separate that too?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `routes.js` file and include all your routes there.

In app.js

`require('./path/to/routes')(app)`;

// add handler for login

`app.use(require('./path/to/login'));`

In routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/therapist-select-days', require('./path/to/therapist-select-days'));
};
```

In therapist-select-days.js

```
'use strict';

let express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //do whatever;
});

module.exports = router;
```

In login.js
add handlers for `login`, `logout` along with the passport steps required to do so.

Comment: What about passport functions?